# How to modify single XML element with ansible instead of appending a new one

Tags: xml, tomcat, xpath, ansible, tomcat9

I want to modify `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml` in order to set up admin user and password. I have this playbook '*working*':

```yaml
- name: Set password from encrypted 'tomcat_admin_pass' for Tomcat User Administrator (admin) using ansible.comunity.xml
  community.general.xml:
    path: "{{ tomcat_live_dir }}/conf/tomcat-users.xml"
    xpath: "/tomcat:tomcat-users/user[@username='admin']"
    # tomcat-users is namespaced and needs more info for XPath
    namespaces:
      tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/xml
    attribute: password
    value: "{{ tomcat_admin_pass }}"
    state: present
    notify: tomcat_reload

- name: Set roles for Tomcat User Administrator (admin) using ansible.comunity.xml
  community.general.xml:
    path: "{{ tomcat_live_dir }}/conf/tomcat-users.xml"
    xpath: "/tomcat:tomcat-users/user[@username='admin']"
    # tomcat-users is namespaced and needs more info for XPath
    namespaces:
      tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/xml
    attribute: roles
    value: "manager-gui,admin-gui"
    state: present
    notify: tomcat_reload
```

But I end up appending two elements like this:

```xml
<user username="admin" password="my_super_pass"/><user username="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
```

I am not very experienced in `XPath` and `ansible.community.xml` but my query seems to be accurate. I expected that ansible would modify only matching elements as per its idempotence behavior.

I did not want to put a Jinja2 template for tomcat-users.xml in case it is manually modified after, and another execution of my role would overwrite it.

Comment: Wondering if it would help to point the XPath at the attributes that you expect to be setting/replacing, rather than the user element? i.e. `xpath: "/tomcat:tomcat-users/user[@username='admin']/@password"` and `xpath: "/tomcat:tomcat-users/user[@username='admin']/@roles"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem here is inconsistent use of XML namespaces. In your expressions, you have written:

```
/tomcat:tomcat-users/user[@username='admin']
```

But if `tomcat-users` is in the `tomcat` namespace, then so is `user`, so you need to write:

```
/tomcat:tomcat-users/tomcat:user[@username='admin']
```

If I use this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    tomcat_admin_pass: secret
  tasks:
    - name: Set password from encrypted 'tomcat_admin_pass' for Tomcat User Administrator (admin) using ansible.comunity.xml
      community.general.xml:
        path: "tomcat-users.xml"
        xpath: "/tomcat:tomcat-users/tomcat:user[@username='admin']"
        # tomcat-users is namespaced and needs more info for XPath
        namespaces:
          tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/xml
        attribute: password
        value: "{{ tomcat_admin_pass }}"
        state: present

    - name: Set roles for Tomcat User Administrator (admin) using ansible.comunity.xml
      community.general.xml:
        path: "tomcat-users.xml"
        xpath: "/tomcat:tomcat-users/tomcat:user[@username='admin']"
        # tomcat-users is namespaced and needs more info for XPath
        namespaces:
          tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/xml
        attribute: roles
        value: "manager-gui,admin-gui"
        state: present
```

With this `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml">
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="role1"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
    <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
    <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  </tomcat-users>
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml">
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="role1"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
    <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
    <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="admin" password="secret" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/></tomcat-users>
```

If I run the playbook a second time, it does not make any additional changes.

---

To expand on the problem a bit:

With your original xpath expression, your first task creates a new `<user>` element in the file...but because the file has a default namespace, you actually end up with a `<tomcat:user>` element. This means that your second task fails to find the element created by the first task, because it's looking for `<user>` rather than `<tomcat:user>`.

Comment: The XPath fix worked flawlessly! I though it 'inherited' namespace from root or something like that.

Comment: If this answer resolved your question, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted". Thanks!